# finding common rows in files based on one column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have 15 files like

> file1.csv

```
a,cg2,0,0,0,21,0
a,cq1,10,0,0,0,0
a,cm2,0,19,0,0,0
...
a,ad10,0,0,0,37,0
```

> file2.csv

```
d,cm1,0,3,0,0,0
d,cs2,0,32,0,0,0
d,cg2,0,0,9,0,0
...
d,az2,0,0,0,21,0
```

.
.
.
.

> file15.csv

```
s,sd1,0,23,0,0,0
s,cw1,0,0,7,0,0
s,c23,0,0,90,0,0
...
s,cg2,0,45,0,0,0
```

I have different number of lines in each file and I want to compare the second field of all 15 files and extract the lines which are common to second field of all 15 files.

in this above case

output is:

cg2

(taking it is common to second field of all 15 files)

I am little new to unix and shell scripting, please help

Comment: Can there be multiple entries where the second field is the same in a single file?

Comment: @F.J. sorry,I did not understand by multiple entries. are you telling that different values corresponding to entries where the second field is the same in a single file ? please cite an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want the full lines from each of the fifteen files where field 2 appears in all fifteen files? Or do you only want a list of the field 2 values that appear in all fifteen files.

The former:

```
a,cg2,0,0,0,21,0
d,cg2,0,0,9,0,0
. . .
s,cg2,0,45,0,0,0
. . .
```

The latter:

```
cg2
. . .
```

If the latter, then this should work

```
awk -F, '{arr[$2]++; if (FILENAME != prevfile) {c++; prevfile = FILENAME}} END {for (i in arr) {if (arr[i] == c) {print i}}}' file*.csv
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk -F, '{
             arr[$2]++; 
             if (FILENAME != prevfile) {
                 c++; 
                 prevfile = FILENAME
             }
         }
         END {
             for (i in arr) {
                 if (arr[i] >= c) {
                     print i
                 }
             }
         }' file*.csv
```

Explanation:

- increment the count of the number of times a field 2 value occurs
- if the filename changes, increment the count of files (the first file changes from a null string to its filename and the count increments from 0 to 1)
- save the current filename
- once all the counting is done, iterate of the array by its keys
- if the count contained in the array is greater than or equal to the number of files, then the field 2 value appeared in all the files (by checking for `>=` instead of `==` this will work in case a value appears more than once in a single file)
- so print the key (which is a field 2 value)
- a glob is used to get all the files, but you could list them explicitly

**Edit:**

Here's a way to print the full matching lines using a two-pass technique. It's a modification of the version above. Make sure to list the files twice.

```
awk -F, '
         FILENAME == first && flag {
             exit
         }
         ! first {
             first = FILENAME
         }
         FILENAME != first {
             flag = 1
         }
         {
             arr[$2]++; 
             if (FILENAME != prevfile) {
                 c++; 
                 prevfile = FILENAME
             }
         }
         END {
             # print the matching lines
             do {
                 if ($2 in arr) {
                     print;
                 }
             } while (getline);
             # print the list of words
             for (i in arr) {
                 if (arr[i] >= c) {
                     print i
                 }
             }
         }' file*.csv file*.csv
```

It depends on the first file in the first group being the same name as the first file in the second group. Using globbing similar to what I've shown will take care of that requirement.

It prints the matching lines (not grouped, though), then it prints the list of words. If you want only one or the other, comment out or remove the loop that you don't want (`do/while` or `for`).

If you print only the full lines, you can pipe the output to:

```
sort -t , -k2,2
```

to have them grouped.

Piping only the list of words to:

```
sort
```

will put them in the same order for easier comparison.

Comment: thank you its working, though a little bit difficult for me to understand. thanks for the explanation also. what if I want the Former, i.e., the full lines from each of the fifteen files where field 2 appears in all fifteen files? former will help me to verify any problem in the files.

Comment: @tanmay: There are a couple of ways to approach printing all the pertinent lines. One would be a modification of the script above which would store *all* the lines from *all* the files in an array. This could take a lot of memory, but could be done in one pass through the files. Another approach would be to take two passes through the files sacrificing speed but not using much additional memory. See my edited answer for one way to do it using two passes. Please feel free to ask any question about things you're having difficulty understanding.

Comment: thank you for all your answers and valuable comments, I have successfully done it.

Comment: Thank you again... I mixed ur method with some grep and temporary storage files and completed it

Answer (score 1):

Fun problem.

One way to do it, entirely in Bash, is as follows.

One thing you will need to invoke is `join -t ',' -1 2 -2 2 file1 file2` to join on the second column of two files.  Before you can join, though, you must sort on the second column.

Do successive joins in a for-loop, because `join` takes only two files as arguments.

*ADDENDUM*

Here is a little transcript showing successive joins.  You can adapt it fairly easily, I think.

```
$ cat 1.csv
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
$ cat 2.csv
7,5,4,3
3,b,s,e
2,f,5,5
$ cat 3.csv
4,5,6,7
0,0,0,0
1,b,4,4
$ join -t ',' -1 2 -2 2 1.csv 2.csv | cut -f 1 -d ',' > temp
$ cat temp
b
f
$ join -t ',' -2 2 temp 3.csv | cut -f 1 -d ','
b
```

The first join (on the first two files) produces the joined value in the first column of the result.  So as you join to file3, file4, file5, etc.  You will be using the first column of the result you are generating, which is why you only need the -2 option.  To keep things very efficient, always cut out all but the first column each time you do the join.

Comment: but in this way I have to take join operation on all possible two file combinations of 15 files and save the whole result and then use the cut operation . As I have at least 20000 lines in each file it would be a large file to operate on and how many for loops i will use to do it ?

Comment: Not quite that bad.  Join file1 against file2, then take the _result_ of that and joing against file3, then the result of _that_ against file4 and so on.  You will only have to do 14 joins.